# Data not appending to FormData Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to upload multiple images for an image upload system using AJAX on Jquery.

However, I'm having trouble getting the FormData object to take in the data from the file input. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="multiform" role="form" action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
            <label for="picture">Upload Pictures</label>
            <input type="file" id="pic_upload_file" name="pics[]" multiple>
            <input type="button" id="pic_upload" name="pic_upload" value="Upload">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$('#pic_upload').click(function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("pics", file);
});
```

This object is created and I can see it in the console, but I dont know how to get the user file input data into it to send to a php script.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly is in your **file** variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a file input that takes multiple files, so you have to get those files and append each one to the formData object

```
$('#pic_upload').on('click', function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData(),
        files    = $('#pic_upload_file').get(0).files;

    $.each(files, function(i, file) {
        formData.append("pics_"  + i, file); 
    });

    $.ajax({
        url         : 'test.php',
        data        : formData,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        type        : 'POST'
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo - i tried this - but the data is just in an input id= 'pic_upload_file' and name ='pics[]' - the $('#pic_upload') is just the id for the button - how can i target the $.each to the files in the $('#pic_upload_files') element?

Comment: Oh, okay! Now I see, you have to get the files from the input then.

Comment: how can i target the files from that input? sorry but i'm a mega noob

Comment: Now i can get the files as an object when I console.log(files), but the $.each is not appending into the formData Grrrrr!!

Comment: You can't inspect the formData object, try sending it and getting the files on the server, should work.

Comment: Actually, if you're using Chrome and open the network tab, you can inspect the request payload and see the files, but just console logging the object won't get you the files.

Comment: wow thanks, trick is you dont need to put all the files into the same key, value pair.